# ASP .NET - Set default values of ListView InsertItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net

For a DetailsView I use the following code:

```
 protected void DetailsView1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DetailsView myDetailsView = (DetailsView)sender;
    //set value to current datetime
    ((TextBox)myDetailsView.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text =
    DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
}
```

When I try to do the same thing for a ListView control (specifically the InsertItemTemplate) I get a 'NullReferenceException' error message.

How do I set the default value of a Listview InsertItemTemplate textbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the [ListView's InsertItem property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.insertitem.aspx):

```
((TextBox)myDetailsView.InsertItem.FindControl("TextBox1")).Text =
    DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy HH:mm");
```

Comment: Thanks - thought it was something like that.